# Fancybox content color

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox

Im using this code to show on screen some fancybox message:

```
   $.fancybox(
    { 
    content: "SomeText", 
    showCloseButton: true,
    transitionIn: "elastic"
    });
```

i want a way to change the color of the content ("SomeText").

how can it be done using html / css?

and how could it be done using fancybox commands?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either go into the fancybox.css file and add/modify the `color:#hexvalue` attribute in a selector, most likely the `#fancybox-content` selector (although I'm not certain).

**OR**

You could simply make your content an html string such as

`content: "<span style='color:#myColor'>Some Text</span>"`